# How to write this PDE in spherical coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, spherical-coordinates

I am interested in solving the following PDE,

$$\Delta u + w(|x|) x\cdot \nabla u = 0,$$

where $u:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}.$

I know that,
$$\Delta u = u_{rr} + \frac{n-1}{r}u_r + \frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{S^2}u$$

and after computation I deduced that $x\cdot \nabla u = r u_r.$

Therefore I am wondering if a general solution to this PDE is of the form,
$$u(r,\theta,\phi) =\sum_{l}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}a_{ml}g_l(r)Y_{ml}(\theta,\phi)$$

where $g_l(r)$ solves,
$$g''+\left(\frac{n-1}{r}+rw(r)\right)g'-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}g=0$$

and the spherical harmonics solve, $$-\Delta_{S^2}Y = l(l+1)Y.$$

Is this expansion correct?

Comment: Where does the $w'$ come from? Also, I think you get one solution $g$ for each $l$, so it should be $g_l$

Comment: @Sal you are right, I fixed the typo.

Comment: One more thing: generally you'd get two solutions for $g$ so you'd need $\sum\dots \left[a_{ml}g_{1,l}+b_{ml}g_{2,l} \right]$

Comment: What is $\omega$? and what is $x$?